# How do I return from a child view to a parent view by tapping a row element in a list in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I need to perform an action similar to "unwind to segue" when the user taps and select a cell row in a list. I'm new to SwiftUI and I would really appreciate if someone can help me.

```swift
struct cellView : View {

    @State var name = ""

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text(name)
            Button(action: { ***unwind to parent view code*** })
        }
    }
}
```

I expect there to be an action code to return to parent view after tapping the cell row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using Enviroment variable called presenationMode, like this:

```
struct CellView : View {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State var name = ""

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text(name)
            Button("Tap me",
                   action: { self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much @LuLuGaGa. Works perfectly! (I tried to give you a vote but had not enough reputation). Thanks again